# RoR - Removing an array element from ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

In my Rails 3.2 application, I am getting the `params` variable in my controller as follows:

```
params.class         => ActionController::Parameters
params[:a].class     => ActionController::Parameters
params[:a][:b].class => Array
params[:a][:b]       => ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

When I try to delete a value in the array, it's not reflecting correctly.

e.g.

```
params[:a][:b].delete('1') 
=> "1"
```

But when I again query it, there is no change in it.

```
params[:a][:b]   => ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Although, if I reassign it to a variable, it's working fine.

```
arr = params[:a][:b]
arr.delete('1')
=> "1"

arr
=> ['2', '3', '4']
```

Any idea why I cannot update the `params` object directly?

Comment: Can you post only `params`  values?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: `params[:a][:b] == ['1', '2']; params[:a][:b].delete('1'); params[:a][:b] == ['1', '2']`. My suspicion is that you've overridden something funny, and `params` is doing something more than I expect. Can you post the full, relevant, controller code? Ideally something reproducible.

Comment: What happens when you do `arr = params[:a][:b] ;
arr.delete('1'); params[:a][:b] = arr; params[:a][:b]` ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have 3.2 rails application? AFAIR `ActionController::Parameters` was introduced in rails 4. In 3.2 params should have following class `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`

Comment: did you get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
params[:a][:b].tap { |ary| ary.delete('1') }
#=> ['2', '3', '4']
```

To change the value of `params[:a][:b]` you'd want assign it a new value:

```
params[:a][:b] = params[:a][:b].tap { |ary| ary.delete('1') }
```

Comment: But what's the difference between this, and `params[:a][:b].delete('1')`? Why would your code work, if the latter does not? I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TomLord fire the console and see the difference ;)

Comment: The *return value* differs, sure. But the mutation of the `params` hash does not - which is the important thing.

Comment: @TomLord thanks to your comment I've just realized that I did not complete the answer editing (did not click `save edit` in another browser window). Thanks for that!

Comment: Sorry, but I **still** don't see any difference between your code, and simply writing `params[:a][:b].delete('1')`. Note that [`Array#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-delete) *mutates* the object; it does not return a new object, like most other non-bang methods.

Comment: @TomLord assigning a new value to `params[:a][:b]` would work, but you're right in a sense, that both ways of modifying of array would do the job.

Comment: That works, but I am not sure why.  Why would delete not work here!